# Binding an integer value using TemplateBinding shows nothing

Tags: c#, xaml, controltemplate, winui-3

I'm trying to bind an integer to a ControlTemplate but shows nothing to me.
here is my `TextBlock` which is a part of my `ControlTemplate`:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14"
           Foreground="#000"
           Text="{TemplateBinding Number}"/>
```

here is my dependency property which is a part of my CustomControl:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Number), typeof(int), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));

public int Number
{
    get => (int)GetValue(NumberProperty);
    set => SetValue(NumberProperty, value);
}
```

I have tried this also, but it doesn't works too:

```
 <TextBlock FontSize="14"
            Foreground="#000"
            Text="{Binding Number, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
```

if I change it to `string` it works

Comment: There's no opportunity to introduce a converter when you're using TemplateBinding. So the types used as the value for the source property and the target property must match. I agree with Dmitrii, if you need a converter you can use the verbose syntax for a template binding: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter="..." ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a converter which will convert int to string value. Here's the example of such converter.

```
public sealed class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return ((int)value!).ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Instead of the `TemplatedBinding` in the control template you should use such statement.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="#000"
           Text="{Binding Number, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConverter}}" />
```

One more thing. You have to define the converter somewhere in your xaml to be able to use it as a `StaticResource`.

```
<c:IntToStringConverter x:Key="IntToStringConverter" />
```

**Update**

Converter is not needed to show integer value as text.

```
 //Working
 Text="{Binding Number, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
 
 //Not working    
 Text="{TemplateBinding Number}"
```

Comment: tnx for the answer, I have tried but it doesn't worked.

Comment: It must work. I have tested it and it shows value without any problem. Can you provide more code? Did you define the converter in resources? Do you have binding issues in the Visual Studio? What is binding issue?

Comment: It says `'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.`

Comment: I used a breakpoint on `Convert` method `value` is `string`. I have removed converter and it worked.

Comment: I'm using`{Binding StimulationNumber, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}` now. please update your answer so I'll be able to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. You said that StimulationNumber is integer how can it be string?

Comment: No problem bro, I have uploaded a full sample [Here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/urxwn6fhj0wq415/TestApp.zip/file), I have used converter there. I need to read more about `Binding` I think.

Comment: I'm checking your project and I've found some issues. If you don't mind I'll let you know about them. F.e. here you set default value as 1 while your have a string value, it should be "1". public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Number), typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(1));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254692/discussion-between-dmitrii-polianskii-and-rezanoei).